# Adding CarPlay Simulator to my React Native App

Tags: react-native, carplay

I'm trying to add the CarPlay Simulator to my React Native app without success!

I've tried running this line of code in my Terminal, but it made no difference...

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlay -bool YES
```

If you have any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To oppen carplay from xCode:

- run ios simulator
- from top-bar select I/O > External Displays > CarPlay